# Customize Control Template of Silverlight Combobox

Tags: silverlight, autocomplete, controltemplate

I want to implement this in Silverlight.

Combobox with an inline filter in the popup

http://gregandora.wordpress.com/2012/01/25/filtering-items-in-a-wpf-combobox/

Unfortunately it's for WPF and XAML is not compatible. It's very hard to convert it or understand how to change the control template of the combobox.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a demo of the solution: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/8424800/StackOverflowSl.html (see ComboBox Filter)

I took the default Silverlight ComboBox template and added a "FilterTextBox" to the Popup section. I couldn't post the whole xaml as it exceeded StackOverflow's limit. The full sources are [here as a GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/3759380). I've left in the important parts. Next, the event handlers on the TextBox needs to be hooked up.

```
<Style TargetType="ComboBox">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBox">
                <Grid>                       
                    <Popup x:Name="Popup">
                        <Border x:Name="PopupBorder"
                                Height="Auto"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                CornerRadius="3">
                            <Border.Background>
                                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1">
                                    <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="#FFFFFFFF" />
                                    <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="#FFFEFEFE" />
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Border.Background>
                            <Grid>
                                <TextBox x:Name="FilterTextBox"
                                            Height="22"
                                            VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                                <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer"
                                                Margin="0,25,0,0"
                                                BorderThickness="0"
                                                Padding="1">
                                    <ItemsPresenter />
                                </ScrollViewer>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </Popup>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Wiring up the TextBox

```
public Q12513294()
{
    // Required to initialize variables
    InitializeComponent();

    InitializeMyCombo(
        Enumerable.Range(1, 99).Select(x => "Beer " + x.ToString() + " on the wall"),
        (object item, string filter) => (item as String).Contains(filter)
    );
}

private void InitializeMyCombo(IEnumerable items, Func<object, string, bool> filter)
{
    MyComboBox.Loaded += (s, e) =>
    {
        // PagedCollectionView implements a filterable collection
        PagedCollectionView list = new PagedCollectionView(items);
        MyComboBox.ItemsSource = list;

        // Set the filter based on the contents of the textbox
        TextBox filterTextBox = MyComboBox.GetTemplateChild<TextBox>("FilterTextBox");
        list.Filter = new Predicate<object>(
            item => filter(item, filterTextBox.Text)
            );

        // Refresh the filter each time
        filterTextBox.TextChanged += (s2, e2) =>
        {
            list.Refresh();
            filterTextBox.Focus();
        };
    };

}

public static class Helper
{
    public static T GetTemplateChild<T>(this DependencyObject parent, string partName)
    {
        return (T)(VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, 0) as Panel).FindName(partName);
    }
}
```